# how to write if the table exists in google bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

In sql server , if the table exists , we truncate this table as below

```
IF OBJECT_ID(XXXX.dbo.XXX', N'U') IS NOT NULL
TRUNCATE TABLE XXXX ;
```

how do we write this logic in google bigquery ?

Comment: How do you write to BigQuery? Do you use a insert query? Do you use a load job?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The query would be like this

```
 TRUNCATE TABLE [[project_name.]dataset_name.]table_name
```

Also here's the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#truncate_table_statement) on data manipulation that google has and there are some examples in how to use truncate